# MDX Count of records

Tags: ssas, mdx

Can anyone please help me with this simple looking MDX query, and tell me why I am getting an infinite recursion error?

```
with member [Measures].[Count of Records] 
as count(nonempty([ResourceId].[ResourceId].members))

select 
    [Measures].[Count of Records] on 0,
    [ProcessDate].[ProcessDate].Members on 1

from [Model]
```

I am trying to get the non null counts of resource ids for each date. This is the error I receive:

```
Infinite recursion detected. The loop of dependencies is: Count of Records -> Count of Records.
```

Comment: My guess is you already have a measure with the same name in your cube.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if did :)

Comment: Try: [Measures].[Count of Records] as 1. Will it work?

Comment: No it didn’t work

Comment: What do yo mean? Same output?

Comment: did you get the answer for this?